# MySQL UNION Statement Slow Query

Tags: mysql

Are there any optimizations that can be done to help get the following statement to execute more quickly and not be marked as "slow" query?

```
SELECT id FROM equipment_acc_1 WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_acc_2 WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_gloves WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_head WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_pants WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_shoes WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_top WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_donation_skins WHERE nick='Cutter29'
    UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM equipment_weapon WHERE nick='Cutter29';
```

All of the tables in this query are exactly the same, here is an example:

```
mysql> describe equipment_acc_1;
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nick     | char(25) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| id       | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cooldown | datetime | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I can't imagine any way to speed it up by changing the query, but if you can modify the table definitions it would probably help to have an INDEX on the `nick` field in each table...oh, nevermind, I just noticed it's the primary key (ie. already indexed)

Comment: What is the `id` field used for?

Comment: @Uueerdo the `id` field is used in another query to pull information from an `inventory` table later on in the code.

Comment: Why don't you use one table for all equipments? Maybe you can consider having a table named "**equipments**" and adding a column named "equipment". I think this can speed your query up and it would be more clear to work on it.

Comment: and/or there should be a "nicks" table, and these tables (or a consolidated equipment table as suggested by @Güney) should reference that by a nick_id integer value, so a string search is only need to get the id for the nick value.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much one can do with unions - but if there guaranteed to be data in all tables, you can try this (use outer joins if data is not guaranteed)

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id, d.id, e.id, f.id, g.id, h.id
from equipment_acc_1 a,equipment_acc_2 b, equipment_gloves c, equipment_pants d, equipment_shoes e, equipment_top f, equipment_donation_skins g, equipment_weapon h
where a.nick='Cutter29'
and b.nick=a.nick
and c.nick=a.nick
and d.nick=a.nick
and e.nick=a.nick
and f.nick=a.nick
and g.nick=a.nick
and h.nick=a.nick
```

Comment: You are missing what you want to select from the statement. I tried selecting ``id`` but it didn't work.

Comment: please try modified query

Answer (score 0):

You can change your design and merge all your small tables to one:

```
Equipment_parts:
Part_id
Equipment_id
Part_type
Part_name
Nick
...
```

Then you can find "cutter29" quickly using index.